# Invert a LUT (lookup table)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, lookup-tables

I am writing some color management code, and I am dealing with LUTs (look up tables).

I can read the color profile LUT and convert my values... but, how can I do the inverse operation? maybe, is there a good algorithm to generate the 'inverse' of a LUT?

Answer (score 1):

If your LUT is a given, the simplest method is to find the closest entry to any given color value.  You can accelerate this computation by a variety of methods; for example, you can build a k-d tree out of your LUT entries and use it to eliminate most of the comparisons an exhaustive check would require.

However, this will tend to result in a "posterized" image, since smooth areas in your image will shift abruptly from one entry to the next.  You can avoid this by taking your pixels in (quasi-)random order, picking the best fit from your LUT, and pushing the difference between the pixel value and the chosen entry back onto the nearby pixels which haven't already been chosen.

There are a variety of ways to do this last, but they all result in a dithering effect that generally makes better use (for imaging purposes) of the available LUT entries than the simple, per-pixel operation can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can usually invert a lookup table efficiently (linear time), **assuming that the function is a bijection**.  If your lookup table maps two different keys to the same value, then there is no direct way to invert the table because you would end up needing to have a value that maps to two different keys.  If you're okay with this that's fine, though it may call into question why you're trying to build the reverse map.

If you know that every value is unique, you can build an inverse lookup table as follows.  First, create a data structure to hold the mapping from values to keys - perhaps a hash table, or a balanced binary tree, or a raw array if the values are small integers.  Next, iterate over each key/value pair from the lookup table, then insert the mapping value → key into the new lookup table.  This can be done in linear time plus the time required to insert the values into the new container.

Comment: input LUT is a many to one, so, i know that there are many solutions for the same output value. But maybe i can get rid of them prefiltering them.